# cannot display the view from the url parameter in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I was trying to display a list of the blog with the same category which display on the url parameter. however when i click the link it still stay at the same page.

route

```
match '/microposts/:category', :to => 'microposts#category_list'
```

view

```
<h2>sidebar</h2>
    <% @categories= Micropost.select("category").group("category")%>
    <% unless @categories.nil? %>
    <ul><% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <li><%= link_to category.category, :controller =>"microposts", :category => category.category,     :method => 'category_list' %></li>

    <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

After click the link enter category_list view.

category_list.html.erb

```
<h2>Catergory</h2>
<% @microposts.each do |post|%>
<article>
    <h4><%= link_to post.title, post %>|        <%= post.created_at %></h4>
</article>
<% end %>
<%= will_paginate @microposts %>
```

microposts controller

```
def category_list
    @micropost = Micropost.select("category").where(params[:category])
    @title = "Category"     
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this:

**UPDATED:**

microposts_controller.rb

```
def category_list
  @microposts = Micropost.where('category = ?', params[:category])
  @categories = Micropost.select('DISTINCT(category)').map(&:category).compact
  ...
end
```

routes.rb

```
match '/microposts/:category' => 'microposts#category_list', :as => :microposts_category_list
```

_sidebar.html.erb

```
<h2>sidebar</h2>
<% unless @categories.empty? %>
  <ul>
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <li><%= link_to category, microposts_category_list_path(category) %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I still couldnt display it even though I have changed it. It automatically go to my index page. with url of http://localhost:3000/microposts?category=written&method=category_list
will be extremely glad if you help me to sort it out... I been baffled by this matter for hours...

Comment: i get undefined method `microposts_category_list_path'
_sidebar is at views/layouts/_sidebar
Need to transfer to the views/microposts/category_list

Thank you for your help. =)